# Adding Duration that contains frames

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a duration that contains frames:

```
e.g1: 00:00:00:00
     hh:mm:ss:FR
```

FR - stands for frames which is 25 frames for the middleast/asia region.

But in C# it takes the last FR as seconds (which is 60seconds).

```
 e.g2: 00:00:00:00
      DD:hh:mm:ss
```

Now how do I add e.g1 in C#

Can I know with this format how do I add two duration.

```
  TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(duration);
  TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30:18");
  TimeSpan t3 = t1.Add(t2);
```

Answer (score 2):

in this duration `"00:00:30:18"` 18 is considered as milliseconds and not frames, so `Timespan.Duration` won't work for you, and you need something custom (for displaying might work but not adding and subtracting):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TimeSpan AddWithFrames(this TimeSpan x, TimeSpan ts)
    {
        int fr = ts.Seconds + x.Seconds;
        TimeSpan result = x.Add(ts).Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,fr/25,0));
        return new TimeSpan(result.Days, result.Hours, result.Minutes, fr % 25);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
 TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(duration);
  TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30:18");
  TimeSpan t3 = t1.AddWithFrames(t2);
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to use this

Comment: @user726720 this is an extension method (if you don't know what is it tell me to decribe more) just paste this code in a class file, and then just you use like you did before. I changed the method name to be different that the `.Add()` to avoid confusion, see my edited answer)

Comment: nice and simple!

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it adds up the last digits and doesn't treat it like frames of 25. E.g if `duration` is 00:00:10:10. it gave the result of 00:00:40:28. Whereas the result should be 00:00:41:03

Comment: No, this still isn't working. The result is 00:00:41:28. I'm expecting the answer to be 00:00:41:03. With the example above.

Comment: please check my answer, do you have a better way to simplify this please.

Comment: with `TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:10:10");
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:30:18");
TimeSpan t3 = t1.AddWithFrames(t2);` I get 00:00:41:03

Comment: @FalcoAlexander, exactly, 10 + 18 = 28, 28 = 1 sec (25 fr) + 3 fr, so add that 1 sec to secs and 3 frame will remain: 10 sec + 40 sec + 1 = 41 sec

Comment: Yes, this seems to work properly. I'm sorry I didn't check this properly earlier as was working with multiple projects. This seems to work, this drops the hours if the hour is a zero. I understand I can put it back together by converting it to string and doing some tests. But can we modify the extension to make it easier, so it doesn't drop the hour. I'm using my own solution for now in the project but would love to switch to this one as it's nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a custom class that handles operations with SMPTE timecodes.
you do not need to reinvent the wheel, as this project handles all different kinds of framerates and frame drops:

https://github.com/ailen0ada/Timecode4net

```
using Timecode4net;

var start = Timecode.FromString(input: "00:00:05:15", frameRate: FrameRate.fps25, isDropFrame: false);
var end = Timecode.FromString("00:00:10:22", FrameRate.fps25, false);
Console.WriteLine((end.TotalFrames - start.TotalFrames)/25.0);
```

gives you 5,28

Comment: tried this library couldn't open in 2010,2013,2015 VS. Gives error while opening. Have you tried this before. Can you suggest the way to use this please.

Comment: @user726720 what error? I just checked it, added code example, runs fine, simply import the Timecode4net Nuget package

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it unless someone has a better way to simplify this, kindly please share

```
            string timecode1 = "00:05:00:04";
            string timecode2 = "00:06:00:24";

            int   hours1 = Int32.Parse(timecode1.Substring(0,2))*90000;
            int   minutes1 =  Int32.Parse(timecode1.Substring(3, 2))*1500;
            int seconds1 = Int32.Parse(timecode1.Substring(6, 2))*25;
            int frames1 = Int32.Parse(timecode1.Substring(9, 2));

            int hours2 = Int32.Parse(timecode2.Substring(0, 2)) * 90000;
            int minutes2 = Int32.Parse(timecode2.Substring(3, 2)) * 1500;
            int seconds2 = Int32.Parse(timecode2.Substring(6, 2)) * 25;
            int frames2 = Int32.Parse(timecode2.Substring(9, 2));

            int time1 = hours1 + minutes1 + seconds1 + frames1;
            int time2 = hours2 + minutes2 + seconds2 + frames2;

            int totaltime = time1 + time2;

            int hours = totaltime / 90000;
           int minutes = ((totaltime % 90000)) / 1500;
            int seconds = ((totaltime % 90000) % 1500 )/ 25;
            int frames = ((totaltime % 90000) % 1500) % 25;
```